# Consulta nfe em Java

Tags: java, web-service

Quero fazer um formulário com o campo chave de acesso e o código *captcha* para ser preenchido. Logo será enviado esses dados para o portal NFE e me retornará as informações da NFE. O *captcha* já consegui fazer funcionar no meu formulário, só não estou conseguindo enviar essas informações.

A url é essa:
http://nfe.sefaz.ba.gov.br/servicos/nfenc/Modulos/Geral/NFENC_consulta_chave_acesso.aspx

Ou essa também:
https://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/consulta.aspx?tipoConsulta=completa&tipoConteudo=XbSeqxE8pl8=

Creio que seria algo do tipo:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpCliente = (DefaultHttpClient) request.getSession().getAttribute("httpClienteCnpj");

BasicClientCookie cookieFlag1 = new BasicClientCookie("flag","1");
cookieFlag1.setDomain("http://nfe.sefaz.ba.gov.br");

cookieFlag1.setPath("/");
httpCliente.getCookieStore().addCookie(cookieFlag1);

List<NameValuePair> lista = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

//teste
lista.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txt_cod_antirobo", receitaBean.getLetras()));
lista.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txt_chave_acesso", "43160988379771003017550010009335021009335027"));
lista.add(new BasicNameValuePair("btn_consulta_completa", "Consulta Completa"));

HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://nfe.sefaz.ba.gov.br/servicos/nfenc/Modulos/Geral/NFENC_consulta_chave_acesso.aspx");
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(lista));

HttpResponse response = httpCliente.execute(post);
```